# Java project template on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, templates, human-interface

I'm trying to expand upon the basic Java that I've learned by taking an example that I've found in a general Java programming book and growing it with more capability.  I've been trying to use Xcode's v3.5.2 Java project template for a Java application using the Eclipse Juno IDE and I see some of the methods and classes are deprecated. After clicking around the internet for the past two or three days, I'm confused.

I have two primary questions:

1. What is the proper start in developing a Java application (not for the web) on a Mac? Is the template available through Xcode 3.5.2 the right way to go? I'm trying to find how the apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar (discussed in the Apple Developer User's Guide for Java) interplays with the Xcode template.  Does one outdate the other?  Should I start from scratch?
2. I have yet to come across any documentation/template for the bare-bones/stub setup of a Java application on the Mac other than what is available in Xcode!  I would think that such a stub would be available given Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. If some reference is available, I would appreciate a link. I've been consulting Apple's Java Development Guide for Mac and the API documentation, Oracle and other places on the web but so far no luck and just confusion.

I get the idea that the true answer is to give up on Java on the Mac and program on the PC or just go with Objective-C! (I'd like to learn Objective C but unfortunately right now, I have better survivability in my company with Java and Python.)

Thanks for any kind suggestions.

Comment: Are you unable to distribute a jar? Does there have to be a native wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Give unto XCode that which is objective c.  Use Eclipse for everything else.

Comment: Yes!  That I understand! :)  And I _am_ using Eclipse, yet the questions remain on how NOT to recreate the wheel every time a relative "newbie", who loves the aesthetics of the Mac interface, wants to create an application...btw, this isn't an "app" for the general market, it's more of some scientific app.  I'm thinking it may be Linux time if I don't hear an answer. :(

Comment: I'm still surprised there isn't some boilerplate template out there that fits Apple's guidelines, but I think I'm able to recreate the wheel on my own now.  Here's my conclusion: 

The template in Xcode is a good guide, but http://www.example8.com/node/view/id/6143 shows how to incorporate System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true"); which is discussed at the Apple Developer site: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html.  So, it is the combination of the two along with the basic Java knowledge.